# Фиксированный размер элемента OpenGL Widget на форме

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Делаю программу по [этому](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18) туториалу.
Добавил на форму элемент `OpenGL Widget` и хочу сделать, чтобы он растягивался при изменении размеров главного окна. Сделал все настройки как в видео (и еще пробовал другие варианты настроек):

- Горизонтальная политика: Expanding
- Вертикальная политика: Preferred

Но при изменении размеров окна размеры элемента остаются фиксированными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пойму, в чем дело

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно для корневого `centralWindget` компоновку (layout) установить. Это если у вас все остальное скомпоновано, иначе нужно везде порядок с компоновкой навести.